# Microsoft Code Analysis. Does Option Infer exist as a rule?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, static-code-analysis, option-infer

I recently ran into an bug caused by the accidental reuse of a variable in a For Each loop in my VB.NET project.

```
Dim iterator As Integer = 0
For Each iterator In {1, 2, 3}
Next
Console.WriteLine(iterator)
```

This code will output '3'
I should have used a different variable name for the For Each loop. The loop was modifying the variable which was used for other purposes elsewhere.

I can prevent this behaviour by turning Option Infer off. However this introduces a lot (3000 ish) errors in a moderate sized project I'm working on.

What I would prefer, is a code analysis rule that flags up the use of For Each without a type declaration.

I've had a quick look through the Code Analysis rules provided with Visual Studio 2017, but can't see a rule. I fear I may have to create a custom rule.

Can anyone clarify that a rule does not exist before I start getting my hands dirty with custom rules?

Comment: Although it would improve correctness, I don't think it would help readability much to have the `For Each` variable shadow the variable in the enclosing scope.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. With Option Infer on, you can use the same variable name for the loop as another in the enclosing scope. You can flag this up by using Option Infer off, however that introduces may compiler errors (correctly) as explained above. So a rule that flags up the use of For...Each without a type declaration would be ideal.

Comment: My point is, if you used `For Each iterator As Integer In ...`, I think that would be legal with `Option Infer Off`, and it would be correct, but I still think it would be undesirable (because `iterator` within the `For Each` scope is different from `iterator` within the routine scope).  But there might already be rules that would flag that.